# How to activate full screen in Microsoft Edge?

Tags: fullscreen, microsoft-edge

How can you activate full screen in Microsoft Edge?

I can't find a menu item for it, and pressing <kbd>F11</kbd> doesn't work, unlike all other major browsers.

Does Edge have a full screen mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Note: This applies for Windows 10 Creators Update or below. If you are on Fall Creators Update (released late 2017) or above, this still works, but there is now an easier way to do it, which is detailed at the bottom.

Being a Universal Windows Platform App, Edge has a full screen mode built in.

All UWP apps can be put into full screen mode by using the <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> key combination. But for some unknown reason, Microsoft hasn't mentioned the feature anywhere in Edge that I can see.

Edge in normal mode:

[image]

Edge in full screen mode:

[image]

Screenshots lifted from [here](https://www.digitaltrends.com/computing/how-to-enable-microsoft-edge-full-screen-mode/)

---

In the Fall Creators Update, Microsoft (finally!) added a fullscreen mode and a button in the menu:

[image]

By pressing this or <kbd>F11</kbd> you can activate the fullscreen mode.

Comment: Just a note.... the new "Fall Creators Update" to Windows 10 will include a menu item in Edge to go to full screen (adjacent to the zoom menu).  This update will most likely be released in the next 4-8 weeks

Comment: @egray thanks - I'm actually on the Fall Creators Update but hadn't noticed this